# how can i share a linked list between two classes

Tags: share

supposed i created a linked list in class A
how can class B access it?
please give me some examples if any 
many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the linked list is maintained by class A. You should create an interface that can be used by class B.

I can think of:

- Add, to add to the linked list
- Delete, to delete from the linked list
- Replace, to replace an item
- Lookup, to get an item from the list.
- Length, to get the length of the list.

And there are possibly more (like an iterator) but it should suit your needs.

An other option is to create it outside class A and B and pass it to the classes at construction.

Comment: i am not sure how to create an interface like that.
would you mind giving me an example? thanks

Comment: Just add the methods needed to manipulate the linked list to class A so class B can access them.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass the list to both classes through a constructor.

```
List<X> list = new LinkedList<X>();
A a = new A(list);
B b = new B(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a linked list? if you use a different structure that you can control the memory space of, you can use shared memory nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can create friend functions for insertion, deletion, traversal etc. and other operations on the link list in class A and , they'll be available for use in Class B.